# Compress a folder to a .tar file in Ubuntu 20.04 via GUI

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, compression

In the past, I had an option to compress to `.tar` file from Nautilus. How can I do that with Ubuntu 20.04? I did not expect new distros progress backward in features.

I am not after a command line solution. I want an options on GUI.

[image: compress ubuntu 20.04]

Comment: `.tar` files aren't compressed. They're merely archives, which are then compressed using gzip, xz, or whatever.

Comment: Start Archive Manager from the menu or type file-roller in command line. Its all done from a separate app called Archive Manager. It does not use Nautilus. There are over 20 compress option plus only tar

Comment: You can use Caja file-manager instead of Nautilus or whole MATE desktop instead of GNOMEs Hell.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Archive Manager]

Install file-roller via

```
sudo apt install file-roller
```

Start Archive Manager from menu. Or on command line as `file-roller`

Comment: installing `file-roller` does not change the menu archiving application to `file-roller`. So, it will act as before. Command line is a no-no solution. I want it back in GUI otherwise you can use `tar ...` command.